# Rails: Multi-level model reference in one command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, content-management-system

I am building a CMS in rails, and at present need to have a dynamic multi-level hierarchy implementation to access the campaigns for those specific restaurants owned by a specific user. In short, the data model I have created is as such:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :restaurants, dependent: :destroy
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    validates  :user_id, presence: true

    has_many :campaigns, dependent: :destroy
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

At present I attempted to implement with a series of dot operations as:

```
 @user.restaurant.campaigns.(method)
```

Yet that has simply yielded in `NoMethodErrors` on `undefined method`campaigns' for #

The action steps are as: 1) User logs in, 2) User has list of restaurants displayed that they own, 
3) User clicks on a certain restaurant and the view dynamically changes to show that restaurants campaigns.
Is there a proper way to implement a multi-level dynamic model reference in rails so that the user could complete the actions outlined as well as stay within one page and avoid navigating away?

**EDIT UPDATED ADDITION**:

At present I have the `show` for the users as:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= gravatar_for @user %>
                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section>
            <% if @user.locations.any? %>
                <div>
                    <%= link_to "Start a Campaign", newcampaign_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
                </div>
                <%= link_to "Manage Locations", uploadlocations_path %>     
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to "Upload Locations", uploadlocations_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %> 
            <% end %>
        </section>
        <section>

            <%# disply list of restaurants%>

            <%= link_to "Add New Restaurant", newrestaurant_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
            <ul class ="campaigns">
                <%= render @restaurants %>
            </ul>

        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <% if @restaurants.any? %>

            <ol class="campaigns">
                <%= render @campaigns, object: @restaurants %>
            </ol>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the user able to click on the specific restaurant in the side menu at `render @restaurants`, which goes to the partial:

```
<ul>
    <span class="content">
        <%= link_to restaurant.name, '#' %>
    </class>
</ul>
```

How can I have a user click on a restaurant in the menu and send that specific restaurant selected back into the `<%= render @campaigns, object: @restaurants %>` in the users `show` page?

Comment: Id say it's probably because you didn't add `attr_accessible`, try adding this line in the restaurant model `attr_accessible :campaings` and tell me if it works

Comment: If you use parameters within the controller you don't need to use attribute accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@restaurant = @user.restaurants.find {|r| r.id == 1 } # or select your particular restaurant
@restaurant.campaigns # 1 query for getting all campaigns for a specific user-restaurant pair
```

OR You may want to eager load restaurants and campaigns

```
@user = User.includes(restaurants: :campaigns)
```

from 1 + n (restaurants) queries to 1 + 1 + 1 queries (a user, all restaurants, then all campaigns)

---

EDIT (OR):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :restaurants, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :campaigns, through: :restaurants
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :restaurants
  validates  :user_id, presence: true

  has_many :campaigns, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :restaurant
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant, inverse_of: :campaigns
end
```

Controller:

```
@user = User.includes(campaigns: :restaurant)
@restaurant_campaigns = Hash.new([]).merge @user.campaigns.group_by(&:restaurant)
@restaurants = @restaurant_campaigns.keys
```

views:

```
@restaurants.each do |restaurant|
  @restaurant_campaigns[restaurant] # campaigns for user-restaurant pair
end
```

Comment: For the first @user.restaurants.Find{id == 1}, how can a user select a specific restaurant? Using the restaurant select partial that I provided? This is the main issue I have, passing the selected restaurant to the same page but in the <div>

Comment: Editted it.

Its, just an example. any restaurant you want.

Comment: in the model the user can only view the restaurants that they own, will your implementation allow for that?

Comment: I updated to show you my view and the sidebar menu. How can the user click on restaurant be implemented? Is it correct to use `link_to`?